# Rendering and Cropping/Stretching an Image Using Slick/OpenGL (using getSubImage)

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, slick2d

I'm trying to recreate a shadow effect on some 2D sprites in a project using Slick. To do this, I'm recolouring a copy of the sprite and stretching it using Slick OpenGL using this method:

```
public static void getStretched(Shape shape, Image image) {

    TextureImpl.bindNone();
    image.getTexture().bind();

    SGL GL = Renderer.get();

    GL.glEnable(SGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL.glBegin(SGL.GL_QUADS);

    //topleft
    GL.glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
    GL.glVertex2f(shape.getPoints()[0], shape.getPoints()[1]);

    //topright
    GL.glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0f);
    GL.glVertex2f(shape.getPoints()[2], shape.getPoints()[3]);

    //bottom right
    GL.glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
    GL.glVertex2f(shape.getPoints()[4], shape.getPoints()[5]);

    //btoom left
    GL.glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 1f);
    GL.glVertex2f(shape.getPoints()[6], shape.getPoints()[7]);

    GL.glEnd();
    GL.glDisable(SGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    TextureImpl.bindNone();
}
```

[This gives the almost the desired effect, aside from the fact that the image is cropped a bit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUNjQ.png)

[image]

[This becomes more extreme for higher distortions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFnbZ.png)

[image]

I'm new to using OpenGL, so some help regarding how to fix this would be great.
Furthermore, if I feed an image into the method that was obtained using `getSubImage`, [OpenGL renders the original image, rather than the sub image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mudNK.png).

[image]

I'm unsure as to why this happens, as the sprite itself is taken from a spritesheet using `getSubImage` and has no problem rendering.
Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm recolouring a copy of the sprite and stretching it

The issue is that you stretch the texture coordinates, but the region which is covered by the sprite stays the same. If the shadow exceeds the the region which is covered by the quad primitive, then it is cropped.
You have to "stretch" the vertex coordinates rather than the texture coordinates. Define a rhombic geometry for the shadow and wrap the texture on it:

```java
float distortionX = ...;

GL.glEnable(SGL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GL.glBegin(SGL.GL_QUADS);

//topleft
GL.glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
GL.glVertex2f(shape.getPoints()[0] + distortionX, shape.getPoints()[1]);

//topright
GL.glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
GL.glVertex2f(shape.getPoints()[2] + distortionX, shape.getPoints()[3]);

//bottom right
GL.glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
GL.glVertex2f(shape.getPoints()[4], shape.getPoints()[5]);

//btoom left
GL.glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f);
GL.glVertex2f(shape.getPoints()[6], shape.getPoints()[7]);

GL.glEnd();
```

---

> [...] if I feed an image into the method that was obtained using getSubImage, [...]  the sprite itself is taken from a spritesheet [...]

The sprite is covers just a small rectangular region of the entire texture. This region is defined by the texture coordinates. You have to use the same texture coordinates as when you draw the sprite itself.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Your explanation has helped me fix the first of my issues. However, I'm not sure that I understand how to fix the 2nd issue. I am obtaining my image from an Image of the sprite sheet using getSubImage. When I use the draw() method directly on the subImage, it renders exactly how I want. Even with this new code, the shadow still shows the original image. Selecting the correct region after the distortions seems unreasonable, so I must be missing something here.

Comment: *"Selecting the correct region after the distortions seems unreasonable"* - Why "after" the distortion? How do you draw the sprite? Can you create a shadow from the subImage?

Comment: I draw the sprite normally by calling draw(x,y,width,height) on the image itself. This works fine for a subImage. When I feed the subImage into the method to render the shadow, it acts as if I gave it the original image rather than the subImage. This is why I'm a bit confused.

Comment: It appears I've gotten things to work. For some reason, the texture size was 0.875 that of the image size. Not sure why, but things look good now. Thanks for the help!